# JointJS Halo without Rappid

Tags: reactjs, graph, jointjs, mindmap

I want to create UI like this. but I don't know how to implement it!!

Project use: ReactJs

Demo link: https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/rappid/v3.5/ui.Halo.html

I use event (cell:pointerdown) but when I drag element missing handle, handle not update that position

```
 let lastClickedElementView: any = null

    paper.on('cell:pointerdown', (elementView) => {
      // Remove highlight from the last clicked elementView
      if (lastClickedElementView) {
        joint.highlighters.mask.remove(lastClickedElementView, 'my-element-highlight')
      }

      // Add highlight to the newly clicked elementView
      joint.highlighters.mask.add(elementView, { selector: 'root' }, 'my-element-highlight', {
        deep: true,
        attrs: {
          stroke: '#0D99FF',
          'stroke-width': 3
        }
      })

      // Update the lastClickedElementView
      lastClickedElementView = elementView
    })
```